# Why does this speech synthesis not work on onload?

Tags: javascript

The test site is here http://dev.golightlyplus.com/playground/speech/index.html

In the JS I'm trying to get the voice to speak onload, but I can only get it working when a button is clicked.

```
window.onload = function() {

    var voiceElement = document.getElementById('welcome-voice');
    voiceElement.speak();
};

var form = document.querySelector('#test-form'),
    element = document.querySelector('#welcome-voice');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    element.speak();
});
```

In the console I'm getting

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

for the onload function.

Why is it not working for onload?

Comment: Might want to add all of the code inside `window.onload`. Also, your site is giving mod security warnings.

Comment: Not sure about the Mod security errors. Updated the URL to explicitly include index.html to see if that helps. The code for onload is now all within the onload function.. similar error though.

Comment: I switched to using setTimeout and the everything seems to be working fine now. Not sure about those Mod security errors.. but the JS works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById` does take an *id*, not a selector like `document.querySelector` does. Remove the `#`.

Comment: Yes, thank you oversight when I changed from querySelector. I'm still getting an error though: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: Which one, `.speak()`? I've never heard of it.